# search for multiple words in a column and then return the position of that term

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-matching

I am working with excel and need some inputs on how we can search for multiple words in a column and then return the position from where the match was found. For example the table whose words i want to check are:

```
Column A  Column B   
North     Carolina  
South     Boston
West      Coast  
East      Central
```

The table i want to check these phrases in is below:

```
Column C
North West Carolina
Western Coastal
Eastern Time for Central
Southern Boston
```

The final output should give me something like below:

```
Column A  Column B   Column D
North     Carolina  1
South     Boston    4
West      Coast     2
East      Central   3
```

Note that we are searching for words in the 2nd table irrespective of the order in which they are. For example even though the first row in 2nd table is North West Carolina, we get a match. The output basically gives us the position of the phrase where we could match our text.

Can this be done in excel somehow?This seems to me like a combination of `match()` and `search()` somehow but i haven't been able to crack it. Can it be done?

I tried the formula listed below but its not working:

```
VLOOKUP(and($A1&"*",$B1&"*"),'Table2'!$D$2:$D$5,1,FALSE)
```

But this doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: what did you try? is it `A` or `B` you wanna search from with parts of the text? If both, there will be a flaw with ex `West`.

Comment: I'd look at using a `SUMPRODUCT()` to sense check for the value using wildcards as TRUE/FALSE statements then multiplying the result by `ROW()`

Comment: Both of the words should be present in the text we are searching in for example if there was only North West in column C first row it shouldn't be mapped to North Carolina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming data starts in row 2)

```
=MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,C$2:C$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,C$2:C$5)),0)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]